# TypeError: app.on is not a function at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, electron

I am just following traversy media electronjs youtube tutorial and copying code for shoppingList Desktop application.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;
let mainWindow;

//listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready', function(){
    //create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    //load html in window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
});
```

Comment: i'm not using electron but it seems to me that this should be `const app = electron();` even though `electron` is not set in this piece of code.

Comment: i tried that but it says electron is not a function i edited the the code this is the exact same code as traversy media

Comment: how are you loading electron before setting `app` variable?

Comment: Is this the tutorial you are using? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN1Czs0m1SU If so, linking it in the question would be helpful.

Comment: So, looking at the edit history the original code is different from the tutorial code, and was broken because you assigned `app = electron` instead of `app = electron.app`. As far as I can tell the tutorial code that is currently in the question is correct and should work. Instead of editing the question, the broken code should be left in the question and the working code should be in an answer explaining what was wrong and how you fixed it. On SO you are [encouraged to answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: sorry this error is like 3 months old so i don't remember correctly how did i solve it but it wasn't related to code. i was just editing with different account to get that account above range where i can upvote my this account questions so ban on this account can be lifted. I sorry for any disturbance.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the entire code, so `electron` is missing or it is on the window object. Try to first check that if you logging `electron` it exists and also `electron.on` exists. IMO your reference does not give you what you are expecting.

Comment: it is their in node modules